# How to get data from loader hook into an array then pass in to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, react-router-dom

please see my code below. I am currently trying to create a gantt chart using syncfusion react gantt charts. The code works fine as is but I now want to change the data in the GanttData array which is the data source for the GanttComponent so that it is dynamic. I am using react router dom to pull in data from a database using the loader hook. Once I get this data I want to pull out some dates and put them in the GanttData array but I don't know how as I can't use useLoaderData unless it is in a function. Can anyone assist? Apologies if this isn't clear. Please let me know if you need more information.

```
export const loader = async ({ request, params }) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await customFetch.get(`/projects`);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error(error?.response?.data?.msg);
    return redirect("/dashboard/all-jobs");
  }
};

const GanttData = [
  {
    TaskID: 1,
    ProjectNo: "29895",
    TaskName: "Stoneybridge WTW",
    StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
    EndDate: new Date("05/21/2019"),
    subtasks: [
      {
        TaskID: 1.1,
        TaskName: "Sodium Carbonate",
        StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
        Duration: 4,
        Progress: 150,
        comments: "unlucky",
        subtasks: [
          {
            TaskID: 1.11,
            TaskName: "Design",
            StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
          {
            TaskID: 1.12,
            TaskName: "Workshop",
            StartDate: new Date("05/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
          {
            TaskID: 1.13,
            TaskName: "Site",
            StartDate: new Date("06/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        TaskID: 1.2,
        TaskName: "PACl",
        StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
        Duration: 4,
        Progress: 150,
        comments: "unlucky",
        subtasks: [
          {
            TaskID: 1.21,
            TaskName: "Design",
            StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
          {
            TaskID: 1.22,
            TaskName: "Workshop",
            StartDate: new Date("05/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
          {
            TaskID: 1.23,
            TaskName: "Site",
            StartDate: new Date("06/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        TaskID: 1.3,
        TaskName: "Ammonium Sulphate",
        StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
        Duration: 4,
        Progress: 150,
        comments: "unlucky",
        subtasks: [
          {
            TaskID: 1.31,
            TaskName: "Design",
            StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
          {
            TaskID: 1.2,
            TaskName: "Workshop",
            StartDate: new Date("05/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
          {
            TaskID: 1.13,
            TaskName: "Site",
            StartDate: new Date("06/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    TaskID: 2,
    ProjectNo: "31139",
    TaskName: "Barra WTW",
    StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
    EndDate: new Date("05/21/2019"),
    subtasks: [
      {
        TaskID: 2.1,
        TaskName: "Sodium Carbonate",
        StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
        Duration: 4,
        Progress: 150,
        comments: "unlucky",
        subtasks: [
          {
            TaskID: 2.11,
            TaskName: "Design",
            StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
          {
            TaskID: 2.12,
            TaskName: "Workshop",
            StartDate: new Date("05/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
          {
            TaskID: 2.13,
            TaskName: "Site",
            StartDate: new Date("06/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        TaskID: 2.2,
        TaskName: "Ammonium Sulphate",
        StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
        Duration: 4,
        Progress: 150,
        comments: "unlucky",
        subtasks: [
          {
            TaskID: 2.21,
            TaskName: "Design",
            StartDate: new Date("04/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
          {
            TaskID: 2.22,
            TaskName: "Workshop",
            StartDate: new Date("05/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
          {
            TaskID: 2.23,
            TaskName: "Site",
            StartDate: new Date("06/02/2019"),
            Duration: 30,
            Progress: 150,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const splitterSettings = {
  position: "30%",
};

const timelineSettings = {
  timelineUnitSize: 60,
  timelineViewMode: "Month",
  topTier: {
    unit: "Year",
  },
  bottomTier: {
    unit: "Month",
  },
};

function GanttChart() {
  const { projects } = useLoaderData();

  console.log(projects);
  console.log(projects[0].projectEnd);
  const taskFields = {
    id: "TaskID",
    name: "TaskName",
    startDate: "StartDate",
    duration: "Duration",
    progress: "Progress",
    child: "subtasks",
  };
  return (
    <GanttComponent
      dataSource={GanttData}
      taskFields={taskFields}
      height="530px"
      width="1200px"
      splitterSettings={splitterSettings}
      allowResizing={false}
      timelineSettings={timelineSettings}
      collapseAllParentTasks={true}
    >
      <ColumnsDirective maxWidth="100" minWidth="70" width="10">
        <ColumnDirective
          field="TaskID"
          width="100"
          maxWidth="100"
          minWidth="100"
        ></ColumnDirective>
        <ColumnDirective
          field="ProjectNo"
          headerText="Project Number"
          width="80"
          allowResizing={false}
          maxWidth="100"
          minWidth="100"
        ></ColumnDirective>
        <ColumnDirective
          field="TaskName"
          headerText="Task Name"
          width="200"
          maxWidth="100"
          minWidth="100"
        ></ColumnDirective>
      </ColumnsDirective>
      <Inject services={[Resize]} />
    </GanttComponent>
  );
}

export default GanttChart;
```

Comment: The `useLoaderData` hook is used in React function components, yes. What exactly is the issue or problem you face using the returned fetched data? Please [edit] to clarify what any specific issue is or what you specifically need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that `GanttData` is a standard JS variable so that each time your component (a JS function) gets rendered (i.e. "run the function"), then the variable `GanttData` is recreated and re-initialized with the hard coded values you have provided it.

If you want to have a variable that holds data, be able to update that data and see that changed data across renders, then you want to use a state variable (`useState()`) or a reference variable (`useRef()`).  The benefit of a state variable is that when you update the value with the "set state function" then the component that has that state variable (the component that calls `useState()`) will cause the component to be re-rendered.  The benefit of reference variables is that you can update their value while not causing the component to re-render.

So in your case I suspect you want to define `GanttData` (which I would recommend to rename as `ganttData`) as a state variable (`const [ganttData, setGanttData] = useState([{ ...... }])`) and then in your `loader()` function update the state variable using `setGanttData()` to put the newly fetched values into `ganttData`, which will then cause the component to re-render showing you the newly obtained values.